# How to undo a launchctl command?

Tags: macos, terminal, macports, launchd

I wish to undo the following command:

`sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist`

I tried:

`sudo launchctl remove /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist`

However, I received the following error:

`launchctl remove error: No such process`

After navigating to the /Library/LaunchDaemons directory, I verified that org.macports.mysql5-server.plist is located there.

How can I remove this service?

Comment: do you see the service in the output from `launchctl list`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OS X commands. apple.stackexchange.com would be a better place.

Comment: The opposite of `launchctl load` is `launchctl unload`.

Comment: sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really "undo" something in launchctl, but what you likely want to do is to disable the daemon that you previously loaded.  Do:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist
```